# My API data does not show up when calling from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, session, handlebars.js

Below is my code to get data from an API and display on my server, the data comes in but does not display on the screen :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const data = require('../data');
const peopleData = data.people;

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const peopleList = await peopleData.getPeople();
    res.render('people/user',{peopleList:peopleList});
  } catch (e) {
    
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Data function:

```
    require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null;
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    
    async function getPeople(){
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SwayamShah97/0f2cb53ddfae54eceea083d4aa8d0d65/raw/d7d89c672057cf7d33e10e558e001f33a10868b2/people.json');
        return data; // this will be the array of people objects
    }
     
    
    module.exports = {
        getPeople
    }
```

Handlebars:

```
    <div>
        <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
        {{#each peopleList}}
        <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
    </div>
```

Not sure why nothing displays, I console log and the data comes in fine.

Comment: I think you should take a closer look at your `people.json` file. It's an object, not an array. You probably want `{ peopleList: peopleList.person }`

Comment: Plus,, the only thing you're exporting is the `getPeople()` function so there is no `.people` property like you are using here: `const peopleData = data.people;`.